# Why is this mapping not onto

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the mapping

$$\phi: \mathbb{C}[x] \rightarrow \frac{\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]}{(x_1x_2 -1)} \cong \mathbb{C}[x_1 , x_1^{-1}]$$
$$x \mapsto x_1$$

It is not hard for me to see that $\phi$ is injective. However, my question is, why isn't $\phi$ surjective. What is the element $b \in \mathbb{C}[x_1 , x_1^{-1}]$ such that $\phi(a)$ could never equal $b$ for any $a \in  \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: $b=x_1^{-1}{{}}$

Comment: oh wow. Thank you. not sure why i couldn't see that.